# Facebook page for an app cannot have the same URL as the app's namespace

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-page

I have a Facebook app and I need to create a Facebook page for it. The app namespace is, for example, my-namespace123, so the app URL would be http://apps.facebook.com/my-namespace123

The problem is that when I create a Facebook page for it, I can't enter http://www.facebook.com/my-namespace123 as the URL and I get the error message: "Web address is not available. Please try another one."

I checked and there appears to be a page with that URL. What is happening? Is it that hyphens are not allowed in the URL? Is there some way of creating a page with that URL? Please help! Thanks =)

Comment: Possibly the page is unpublished. Just because we can't see it, doesn't mean its not already taken... It's also a pretty generic name - I can easily see someone choosing that name for their own testing purposes. Not much you can do about someone taking the namespace you wanted

Comment: I see your point. The real name is not my-namespace123 but I can't type it here for security reasons. Anyway, I am confused because that URL is allowed for http://apps.facebook.com/whatever-name-01234 but not for http://www.facebook.com/whatever-name-01234 (page) and I'd like to be sure that someone else has that page URL, or if there is another reason I can't use it.

Comment: You won't be able to verify that unless Facebook or the owner releases that information.

Comment: So you're confirming that page URLs can use hyphens and that is not the problem?

Comment: [Actually no, it doesn't allow hyphens](http://i.imgur.com/XNgig.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you don't need to add dashes in http://www.facebook.com/my-namespace123

if your URL is http://www.facebook.com/mynamespace123, you will be able to access it through http://www.facebook.com/my-namespace123

e.g. http://www.facebook.com/A-p-p-S-t-o-r-e

Comment: I really don't recommend relying on undocumented behaviour, especially undocumented behaviour which appears to be in direct contravention to what's documented - but if you're happy to take the chance, go for it :)

Comment: right, don't include it in your plans please!,It just happens to be a solution right now :)

Answer (score 2):

Hyphens aren't supported in usernames for users or pages according to Facebook's help center:
https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=105399436216001

`Usernames can only contain alphanumeric characters (A-Z, 0-9) or a period (".").`